# Beginning ArduPilot

Tags: arduino

I was browsing through the web when I came across the ArduPilot community page. I had heard about Arduino but not ArduPilot.

Now I have a project to build a UAV, as a part of a student challenge or something like that. The problem is: Although I have some experience in 8051, I have none in Arduino. I have fairly good grasp of programming in C and  C++, but have never tried Arduino and obviously not ArduPilot.

Now my problem is: I have to build a UAV (it can be an RC controlled one, but I prefer Autopilot +RC control). I found that ArduPilot shall be the best option due to the limited time (2 Months), but I have no prior experience.

So what study materials are suggested for someone like me to begin from Arduino to Ardupilot (not a professional, but a capable hobbyist)?

I am willing to put in extra effort (as much as required), but I want to be ready for it.

Note: The ArduPilot code may not need much modification. I have to attach an EM sensor to detect power leakages on the transmission line. The sensor shall be attached to the UAV, which will be guided by NAVpoints. Data logging and two way telemetry are also required.

Please suggest an ArduPilot board with all features so that I don't fall short on hardware resources.

Comment: If you can post your requirements it will help in assisting you with finding a board that will be suitable.  Currently, this question is incomplete.

Comment: its closed though..i didnt make it to the finals.. but still it would be  a great thing to learn..

Comment: i have never worked with arduino and also i am new to AutoPilot arena

Comment: my requirement is to build a UAV Plane that will fly along the electrical transmission lines and detect any power leakages..the plane would also require a camera, powerfull enough to enable remote navigation by a person through first person camera, a two way telemetry, data logging among other functions

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been working with the Cyclone frame kit on aeroquad.com and have been pretty happy with the community support for building and programming.  We are  using an Android phone to do our automation, so I cannot speak specifically to Ardupilot.  If you go with the Arduino Mega and the suggested add-on shield as listed on Aeroquad's wiki, it is pretty straightforward.

The documentation and community support through forums, FAQs, etc. on both arduino and Aeroquad is good (neither is very complicated to begin with), and if you check out those resources you will probably be set.